# Anki - finding success rate by interval

Tags: anki

I've been using Anki for about two years now, and have 5,000-odd cards. I am trying to optimise the algorithm and think it would be useful to find out when on average I am most likely to forget cards.

Is there any way of getting stats for at what interval I am most likely to answer 'Again' to a card (maybe through an add-on to statistics or even downloading my data and importing into a spreadsheet)?

Comment: I should say a good answer would help me to, say, find out that my ability on average to recall sharply declines after 23 days or something.

Comment: I think you should post this question on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/Anki/, as far as I can see you can reach people working on it.